# window.open returns null as child window reference in edge browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

This is a part of my code written in my application' JS file:

```
var myUrl="https://www.google.com";
var myArr=[];
var childWin= window.open(myUrl,'_blank');
myArr.push({chidlWindowHandle:childWin});
console.log(myArr.chidlWindowHandle);
```

It prints the child window object in chrome and firefox. But it returns null in edge browser.

Can anybody tell me how  to get the child window reference in Edge as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Known bug, it seems: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/14142493/

Comment: Ok. Thanks @CBroe